# weighted table data frame with plyr

Tags: r, plyr, survey, weighted

I'm working with survey data consisting of integer value responses for multiple questions (y1, y2, y3, ...) and a weighted count assigned to each respondent, like this:

```
foo <- data.frame(wcount = c(10, 1, 2, 3),        # weighted counts
                  y1 = sample(1:5, 4, replace=T), # numeric responses
                  y2 = sample(1:5, 4, replace=T), #
                  y3 = sample(1:5, 4, replace=T)) #
>foo
  wcount y1 y2 y3
1     10  5  5  5
2      1  1  4  4
3      2  1  2  5
4      3  2  5  3
```

and I'd like to transform this into a consolidated data frame version of a weighted table, with the first column representing the response values, and the next 3 columns representing the weighted counts. This can be done explicitly by column using:

```
library(Hmisc)
ty1 <- wtd.table(foo$y1, foo$wcount)
ty2 <- wtd.table(foo$y2, foo$wcount)
ty3 <- wtd.table(foo$y3, foo$wcount)

bar <- merge(ty1, ty2, all=T, by="x")
bar <- merge(bar, ty3, all=T, by="x")

names(bar) <- c("x", "ty1", "ty2", "ty3")
bar[is.na(bar)]<-0
>bar
  x ty1 ty2 ty3
1 1   3   0   0
2 2   3   2   0
3 3   0   0   3
4 4   0   1   1
5 5  10  13  12
```

I suspect there is a way of automating this with plyr and numcolwise or ddply. For instance, the following comes close, but I'm not sure what else is needed to finish the job:

```
library(plyr)
bar2 <- numcolwise(wtd.table)(foo[c("y1","y2","y3")], foo$wcount)
>bar2
        y1       y2       y3
1  1, 2, 5  2, 4, 5  3, 4, 5
2 3, 3, 10 2, 1, 13 3, 1, 12
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: hi, what survey are you working with?  this looks like multiple imputation which needs the `mitools` + `survey` packages to get the confidence intervals correct.

Comment: I'm working with the U.S. Residential Energy Consumption Survey (RECS) from the EIA, among others. Nice to see there is a package for just about everything, thanks for the references!

Comment: that's just a replication-based survey.  you're trying to re-invent the wheel..  you will have a much easier time [replicating their official methods](http://www.eia.gov/consumption/residential/methodology/2009/pdf/using-microdata-022613.pdf) if you use the survey package.  :)

Comment: This is what happens when an ignorant engineer attempts to solve what looks like a basic problem in another discipline he did not know exists. Thanks for the enlightenment! Looks like I have a lot more reading to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a **plyr** answer, but this struck me as a reshaping/aggregating problem that could be tackled straightforwardly using functions from package **reshape2**.

First, `melt` the dataset, making a column of the response value which can be named `x` (the unique values in `y1`-`y3`).

```
library(reshape2)
dat2 = melt(foo, id.var = "wcount", value.name = "x")
```

Now this can be cast back wide with `dcast`, using `sum` as the aggregation function.  This puts `y1`-`y3` back as columns with the sum of `wcount` for each value of `x`.

```
# Cast back wide using the values within y1-y3 as response values
    # and filling with the sum of "wcount"
dcast(dat2, x ~ variable, value.var = "wcount", fun = sum)
```

Giving

```
  x y1 y2 y3
1 1  3  0  0
2 2  3  2  0
3 3  0  0  3
4 4  0  1  1
5 5 10 13 12
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I've been using melt forever, but I'm a cast newbie, so this was very helpful. For learning purposes, I'm still interested in understanding if/how this could be accomplished using ddply, and if not, why not.

Answer (score 0):

you are describing a survey data set that uses replicate weights.  see http://asdfree.com/ for many, many examples but for recs, do something like this:

```
library(survey)

x <- read.csv( "http://www.eia.gov/consumption/residential/data/2009/csv/recs2009_public.csv" )
rw <- read.csv( "http://www.eia.gov/consumption/residential/data/2009/csv/recs2009_public_repweights.csv" )
y <- merge( x , rw )

# create a replicate-weighted survey design object
z <- svrepdesign( data = y , weights = ~NWEIGHT , repweights = "brr_weight_[0-9]" )

# now run all of your analyses on the object `z` ..
# see the `survey` package homepage for details

# distribution
svymean( ~ factor( BASEHEAT ) , z )

# mean
svymean( ~ TOTHSQFT , z )
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! FWIW, my ultimate goal is not to find summary stats with CIs, but rather to explore the distributions of several continuous responses (e.g., temperature settings) using weighted histograms and weighted empirical cdf plots in lattice, which does not support weights (except in densityplot), so I had to reformat the data a bit to show what I want. Survey offers some of these features, but I prefer the multi-panel conditioning capabilities for plotting in lattice. Will need to spend some time playing with survey to see if/how they can work together.